# Docusaurus Admonitions not working since upgrade from V2 to V3

Tags: docusaurus

It was working on version 2, but from version 3, the admonitions are rendered in simple text, without the special design.

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
    "clear": "docusaurus clear",
    "serve": "docusaurus serve",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus write-translations",
    "write-heading-ids": "docusaurus write-heading-ids"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@algolia/events": "^4.0.1",
    "@docusaurus/core": "^3.1.1",
    "@docusaurus/plugin-google-tag-manager": "^3.1.1",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "^3.1.1",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.21",
    "acorn": "^8.7.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "docusaurus-theme-search-typesense": "^0.15.0",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chrono": "^1.13.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

file.md:

```
:::danger
Deleting a Daily RDF or entire Dataset is an irreversible operation.
:::
```

It should show the correct design.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, it should work:

```
:::danger

Deleting a Daily RDF or entire Dataset is an irreversible operation.

:::
```

I think doing it the way you did gets parsed as a single line and not treated as an admonition. This might be a change in the version of MDX.